# Codeigniter ajax insert success redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this insert function with ajax, now, when I have successfully inserted a value, I wanted to redirect the page via ajax.

Here is my controller:

```
public function create(){


    $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('PROVINCE','Province Name','trim|required|max_length[30]|callback_if_exist');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger"','</p>');

    if($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE){

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            # code...
            $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
        }

    }else{

        $data['success'] = true;
        $data = array(
                'PROVINCE' => $this->input->post('PROVINCE'),
            );
        $insert = $this->Provinces_Model->save($data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));

        $this->index;

    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And here is my javascript:

```
<script>

    $('#form-user').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var me = $(this);

        // perform ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: me.attr('action'),
            type: 'post',
            data: me.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                if (response.success == true) {
                    // if success we would show message
                    // and also remove the error class
                    $('#the-message').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>' +
                        ' Data has been saved' +
                        '</div>');
                    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')
                                    .removeClass('has-success');
                    $('.text-danger').remove();



                }else{
                    $.each(response.messages, function(key, value) {
                        var element = $('#' + key);
                        element.closest('div.form-group')
                        .removeClass('has-error')
                        .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                        .find('.text-danger')
                        .remove();
                        element.after(value)
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

This one saves the data successfully but isn't redirecting to another page.

I'm new to ajax, and I want to learn how I can redirect this to my page without loading my templates.

added - model

```
public function save($data)
{
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: either you want to redirect to another page or reload the same page?  because you are addding a div on success on same page

Comment: i want to redirect it after success.

Comment: i just saw that codes on the net and modified it. so i still dont have any idea how i can redirect it

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if (response.success == true) {
    // no extra code
    // url where you want to redirect
    location.href = "<?php echo base_url('class/function'); ?>";
}
```

in your success function

Comment: i need the extra code for the validations, so that if the validation fails, then i corrected it, the failed notification will be removed

Comment: you are handling it in else block

Comment: error of `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: comment out `echo json_encode($data);` and `$this->index` and check again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114512/discussion-between-kev-m-and-vishal).

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(response) {
        if (response.success == true) {
            // if success we would show message
            // and also remove the error class
            $('#the-message').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' +
                '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>' +
                ' Data has been saved' +
                '</div>');
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')
                .removeClass('has-success');
            $('.text-danger').remove();

            //perform redirect
            window.location = "Your desired url";


        }
```

Comment: `window.location = "Your desired url";` will it be something like `<?php echo site_url('Class/function')?>`

Comment: <?php echo "'".site_url('Class/function')."'"?> - I suggest using quotes when passing variables from php to javascript

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function(anonymous function) @ app.min.js:13i @ jquery.min.js:2fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2ready @ jquery.min.js:2K @ jquery.min.js:2

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function inside your success event.

```js
   setTimeout(function () {
   location = '<?= base_url(); ?>ControllerName/MethodName';
                                }, 2000);
```

finally your code should look into this

```js
 if (response.success == true) {
     // if success we would show message
     // and also remove the error class
     $('#the-message').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' +
     '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>' +
     ' Data has been saved' +
     '</div>');
     $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')
     .removeClass('has-success');
     $('.text-danger').remove();
   
    function () {
         setTimeout(function () {
         location = '<?= base_url(); ?>ControllerName/MethodName';
                   }
                    , 2000);
             });
```

several times tested & proven code

Comment: it says `You must use the "set" method to update an entry`. when i saved something

Comment: it now just do `echo json_encode($data);` the and echo `{"status":true}{"PROVINCE":"asdasdasdasd"}`

Comment: i got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

Comment: if you sent me your model save method I can answer well

Comment: also add total message of Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: please use this updated code
setTimeout(function () {
         location = '<?= base_url(); ?>ControllerName/MethodName';
                   }
                    , 2000);

Comment: please use update code.i've tested it now again.now its ok.

Comment: still just echoes {"PROVINCE":"asdsadasd","success":true}

Answer (score 0):

i just did added

```
                $('.alert-success').show(10, function() {
                    $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                        //window.location = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Provinces/index";
                    });
                })
```

my javascript now looks like

```
$('#form-user').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var me = $(this);

    // perform ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: me.attr('action'),
        type: 'post',
        data: me.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.success == true) {
                // if success we would show message
                // and also remove the error class
                $('#the-message').append('<div>' +
                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>' +
                    ' Data has been saved' +
                    '</div>');
                $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')
                                .removeClass('has-success');
                $('.text-danger').remove();

                // reset the form
                me[0].reset();

                // close the message after seconds
                $('.alert-success').show(10, function() {
                    $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                        //window.location = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Provinces/index";
                    });
                })
            }
            else {
                $.each(response.messages, function(key, value) {
                    var element = $('#' + key);

                    element.closest('div.form-group')
                    .removeClass('has-error')
                    .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                    .find('.text-danger')
                    .remove();

                    element.after(value);
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```